# Any linear transformation in $\mathbb{C}$ (complex vector space) is a multiplication by $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

In the Linear Algebra Done Wrong book, one of the exercises was to show that any linear transformation in $\mathbb{C}$ is a multiplication by $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$.

Here's the proof in the solutions part:

"Suppose $T:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a linear transformation. Let $T(1)=a+ib$. Then, $T(-1)=-T(1)=-a-ib$. Since $i^2=-1$, we have $T(-1)=T(i^2)=iT(i)$, which means $T(i)=\frac{-a-ib}{i}=i(a+ib)$. So, for any $w=x+iy \in\mathbb{C}$, we have

$\begin{align*} 
T(w) &= T(x+iy) \\
&= xT(1)+yT(i) \\
&= x(a+ib)+yi(a+ib) \\
&= (x+iy)(a+ib) \\
&= wT(1)."
\end{align*}$

I understand this proof. However, I don't understand what is wrong with the following proof. (I assume there is an error in it because it is much shorter, and the proof in the book seems a little convoluted if my proof is correct.)

"Let $T:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a linear transformation. Let $T(1)=a+ib$ and $z=x+iy \in \mathbb{C}$. Then:

$\begin{align*}
T(z) &= T(x+iy) \\
&= T(x)+T(iy) \\
&= xT(1)+iyT(1) \\
&= (x+iy)T(1) \\
&= zT(1)."
\end{align*}$

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more general fact is that every linear map from a 1-dimensional vector space to itself is multiplication by some scalar. If $V$ is a vector space such that $\dim V = 1$ and $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,V)$, we know that some nonzero vector $v$ generates $V$, so we may ask what $T$ does to $v$.

Since $Tv \in V$, there must be some scalar $\lambda$ such that $Tv = \lambda v$.

Now let $w \in V$ be arbitrary. Then $w = \alpha v$ for some scalar $\alpha$, so
$$ Tw = T(\alpha v) = \alpha Tv = \alpha ( \lambda v) =\lambda (\alpha v) =\lambda w. $$

Answer (score 5):

Nothing. An even shorter proof would be $T(z)=T(z.1)=zT(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is up with the book, but both proofs are too much going into the structure of $\Bbb{C}$.

Let $F$ be a field and consider $F$ as a vector space over itself. Let $T$ be a linear transformation on $F$, then for $\alpha\in F$,  $T(\alpha)=T(\alpha\cdot1)=\alpha T(1)$. Now put $F=\Bbb{C}$.

So there is no need to juggle with $i$.